# Can we implement Drag n Drop with touch events for mobile view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, touch-event

I am using simple HTML-5, and using Drag n Drop feature in React JS, without any library. I have implemented on web, it's working good but when i come to mobile it doesn't work. There are touch events to handle touch things for mobile but i am not achieve any solution. Please recommend some thing which works well.

Answer (score 0):

There are few shim libs that emulate HTML5 drag and drop on mobile devices.

Example: [DragDropTouch](https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch)

They usually clone element that you try to drag on `touchstart`, copy all styles and put it to body, after that on `touchmove` they change position of this element and emulate drag events

The same I do when emulate native drag&drop inside [dragee](https://dragee.github.io/). It's work good on mobile devices as was developed to work on them and support multi touches

Comment: The demo for the suggestion you made doesn't work in Chrome in mobile mode emulator.

Comment: @zmechanic, Thanks, just `const isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window` return false in Chrome mobile mode emulator. Which I used to define that device is touchable. I will review this behavior.